# Universal Links on private LAN

Tags: ios, ios9, ios-universal-links

I'm trying to make Universal Links work in my app as a replacement of URL Schemes, because since iOS 9 it looks like the system is displaying an alert dialog everytime an app is invoked from Safari. I was hoping that replacing the URL scheme call for a registered URL path in Associated Domains while using Universal Links was going make the dialog disappear.

So instead of calling `myscheme://app?params=values` I would call `https://example.com/universal-link/wakeup?params=values`.

My apple-app-site-association (unsigned) file looks like this

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "XXXXXXXX.com.company.appid",
                "paths": [ "/universal-link/*" ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Please note that, for now, I am using a webserver hosted in the company's LAN, it is not a public server on the Internet. So in the app capability "Associated Domains" I wrote something like `applinks:host.company.lan:7700`, yet the **apple-app-site-association file is never fetched** after the app first starts.

I don't know what else to try, so I am considering the server being in a private network might be an issue.

Comment: This will not work. Apple will not scrape private LANs. If you look through the device logs (not application logs), you will likely see a message like: `Sep 21 14:27:01 Derricks-iPhone swcd[2044] <Notice>: 2015-09-21 02:27:01.878907 PM [SWC] ### Rejecting URL 'https://examplecustomdomain.com/apple-app-site-association' for auth method 'NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust': -6754/0xFFFFE59E kAuthenticationErr` [more info here](https://dev.branch.io/recipes/branch_universal_links/#troubleshooting)

Comment: Sorry, you're more likely to see this error: `Oct  6 17:15:00 Derricks-iPhone swcd[4351] <Notice>: 2015-10-06 05:15:00.357483 PM [SWC] ### Download URL 'https://host.company.lan:7700/apple-app-site-association' failed: NSURLErrorDomain, -1003/0xFFFFFC15 kCFURLErrorCannotFindHost`

Comment: Actually, I've checked, and what I see is the first error you posted

Comment: Interesting, then it does seem to be scraping it, but doesn't like that it isn't served over TLS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this [question](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16531) in the Apple developer forum that sheds some light on this.

Looks like the issue is, the apple-app-site-association hosted by a domain signed by an untrusted root, and doesn't matter if you install your root certificate in the system, it won't download either. I assume it must be signed by a CA already included in iOS by default.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work on a private network, but I had to trust the certificates on the device.

To test on a simulator you can drag the certificates into the simulator, on a device you can mail it to the device or airdrop it to it

Answer (score 0):

I´ve been trying with the Developer mode (Associated Domains switch) and this make work for internal domains inside a VPN, but I think this is not the best solution for non technical users.

The Default option following the Apple´s WWDDC´20 video is to install the Root certificate as trusted in the device. But this is not working, at least for me.